# My Anet E12 USB keep disconect but still able to print from SD

Tags: usb

The problem with my Anet E12 should be on USB connection itself.

1. If powered down, the board still gets power from USB
2. If board is resett, USB will still connect
3. Still works on SD; seem like most part not damage.
   What cause the problem? Where to check first? How to fix it?

Note: This printer worked with no problem before.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a power saver issue.  Make sure things like your USB ports, hard drive, or anything you need the printer program to access doesn't turn off in power save.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the problem. these shameful for me but I decide to share it anyway.
I live in apartment that didn't have earth ground in receptacle. Small electrical shock reallly bother me. althought it also destroy some sensitive component mosfet. (current flow through capacitor in switch mode power supply) Then one day I decide to get rid of these. I hammer ground rod and wire it to some receptacle. these when the whole problem start.
The print shockme many time so I decide to give it a ground but I have no problem with PC so.. I don't give ground to PC.
When these thing connected seem like there are some ground potential diffence. that current flow via ground (shield of USB cable) make PC uncomfartable and disconnect usb device.
luckily pc not broken. I give ground to both device and evrything work fine in harmony again.